# How to save data in Java? Hotel Application

Tags: java, database, save

I am developing a small app for hotels. I am using java and mysql. I use mysql to save booking information and guest data and so on.
But now I want to make my program to be more flexible. 
For example if I want to add more apartments(store apartment names) or change the payment methods. At this time I store the data as binary in files and read them from there when I start the program or when I need them.
Is this method correct? or is a better way? Should I use the mysql and read the data from there?

Comment: It depends on your needs, but a database isn´t a bad decision in allmost all cases.

Comment: When you say on your needs? what do u mean?? if i want to store lot of information? or if i want it faster?

Comment: you use mysql but store the data in binary files. in what way do you use mysql if not for storing data?

Comment: @Aツ i use mysql for booking data not application configuration data...and i was not sure if should use it for configuration data as well

Comment: @nikos134 if you just want to represent the application configuration. I think it could be a solid way to go with an xml, which could represent your configuration.

Comment: @nikos134 i'd consider applikation configuration whats not exist in reality like database connections. data like room lists or payment methods are data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a mySQL database. Store the data in tables with different columns based on the info. Use the tables to store the information so you don't need to convert it to binary.

To talk to the table, use the JDBC. There is a nice [tutoral](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-select-query-example) on using JDBC with mySQL. Refer to the SQL website on setting up tables on your mySQL database.

Comment: I already use the mysql to save booking data (e.x price, checkin,nights guest data)...so i should use mysql to store configuration data of the application ?

Comment: @nikos134 You should just leave that data locally on a text file.